# Formatting date issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUMBER, PROCESSDATE
FROM INVENTORY
```

Result:

```
ACCOUNT   PROCESSDATE
5646546   11082021
4654646   11082021
```

The date is in the wrong format.

NOTE: I checked the table design and the `PROCESSDATE` field seems to be an integer.

What code I have tried:

```
.-format(PROCESSDATE, 'DD/mm/yyyy') as PROCESSDATE [the result is DD/mm/yyyy in the column)
.-CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(6), PROCESSDATE) + '01') myDate [The result is an error]
.-CONVERT(CHAR(10), PROCESSDATEAS Datetime) as 'MyDateTime' [the result is an error]
```

Desired output: Obtain `PROCESSDATE` field as `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Date formatting is normally a client-side/presentation concern. What's the schema of the `INVENTORY` table? Based on your result set the `PROCESSDATE` column looks like a `CHAR(..)` or `NVARCHAR(..)` type, not `DATE` or `DATETIME` - and I'd be very concerned if it were `INT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DATEFROMPARTS` to parse the parts and then format 101 to put in MM/DD/YYYY format.  Something like this

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUMBER, 
       PROCESSDATE,
       calc.dt,
       convert(varchar(12), calc.dt, 101) vc_with_date_format
FROM (values (5646546, 11082021),
             (5646546, 11082021))
             INVENTORY(ACCOUNTNUMBER, PROCESSDATE)
     cross apply (values (datefromparts(right(PROCESSDATE, 4),
                                        substring(cast(PROCESSDATE as char(8)),3,2),
                                        left(PROCESSDATE, 2)))) calc(dt);
```

[EDIT] Without the virtual table (which was for demo only)

```
SELECT i.ACCOUNTNUMBER, 
       i.PROCESSDATE,
       calc.dt,
       convert(varchar(12), calc.dt, 101) vc_with_date_format
FROM INVENTORY i
     cross apply (values (datefromparts(right(i.PROCESSDATE, 4),
                                        substring(cast(i.PROCESSDATE as char(8)),3,2),
                                        left(i.PROCESSDATE, 2)))) calc(dt);
```

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER   PROCESSDATE dt          vc_with_date_format
5646546         11082021    2021-08-11  08/11/2021
5646546         11082021    2021-08-11  08/11/2021
```

Comment: The field processdate has a few more records. How would the code look if I had to include the whole processdate column, rather than 2 records?

Comment: @CarlosDiaz just replace the virtual table aliased as INVENTORY with your table.  Your table could have any number of rows

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible format.  Note that if the day is less than 10, then the length of the integer changes.  Arggh!

So, my recommendation is to convert to an 8-character string (with a leading `'0'` if necessary), then construct a canonical date string (`'YYYYMMDD'`).  And convert to a date:

```
select convert(date,
               right(format(processdate, '00000000'), 4) + substring(format(processdate, '00000000'), 3, 2) +left(format(processdate, '00000000'), 2)
              )
```

You can actually move the `format()` to a subquery, CTE, or `values` clause, as in:

```
select convert(date, right(v.processdate_str, 4) + substring(v.processdate_str, 3, 2) +left(v.processdate_str, 2))
from inventory i cross apply
     (values (format(i.processdate, '00000000'))
     ) v(processdate_str)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=915c059c925ee4c1c66a4ccd22d78f0e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried your both queries and I get the following message: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz . . . I actually had tested the logic and include a db<>fiddle.  That suggests that you have badly data -- not surprising when the wrong types are being used.  You can use `try_convert()` to convert the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I think your dates are stored as `ddMMyyyy` in the DB. You can get the desired result by applying the following conversion:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(PROCESSDATE, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'),103), 101)
```

Comment: I tried your code an I got the following error message: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: it worked fine for me, please see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e89b6f9ec076cb4e9957820259115a88).

Comment: I saw the fiddle and it worked...But in my sql I keep on getting the message: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Completion time: 2021-08-12T09:45:51.2456534-04:00

Comment: what are the distinct lengths of the field 'PROCESSDATE' in your table (must be 8)? and it's stored as ddMMyyyy in that table, right?